# Write to custom eventlog eny source

Tags: c#, event-log

I use C# 4.5.
I write logs by System.Diagnostics.EventLog.
I need creatre my source log with name "AB".
But, I need to write to this source all loga that start with "AB", for example :
"AB.BL.Executer".
How can I do it ? 
Can I do it?

Comment: There are several ways of doing it. Either implement IEventLog or an extension method, that the developers of your code need to use for logging. You also can get some inspiration here : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335748/extendable-functionality-for-pluggable-options-in-c/339801

Comment: Like a filtered TraceListener? Take a look into [TraceListener.Filter Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzz7td9t(v=vs.110).aspx try using the constructor that allows you to define the Log name and Source to achieve the desired result.